# Call Azure AD protected API from React

Tags: reactjs, axios, azure-active-directory, react-hooks, azure-ad-msal

I have a react web-app which needs to access an ASP.NET Core API hosted in Azure. Both apps are protected by Azure AD. I have registered the apps separately in Azure AD App registrations. I have exposed the API which gave me this scope: api://{api_azure_client_id}/user_impersonation - this scope allows both users and admins to consent. I registered the react app separately and gave it permission to access the exposed the API scope.

I am using MSAL to acquire tokens. I can successfully sign but I don't know how to acquire the access_token to call the API. I am following the [the azure ad samples for react here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/react-sample-app). The decision to use hooks was inspired by [this pull request on the sample.](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/1206/commits/f05dfaae8c9cea9d0e8f93be4ff14779014ad42d)

MSAL config:

```
export const GRAPH_SCOPES = {
 OPENID: "openid",
 PROFILE: "profile",
 USER_READ: "User.Read",
 API_CALL: "api://{api_azure_client_id}/user_impersonation"
};

       export const GRAPH_ENDPOINTS = {
        ME: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
      };

   export const GRAPH_REQUESTS = {
     LOGIN: {
      scopes: [
        GRAPH_SCOPES.OPENID,
        GRAPH_SCOPES.PROFILE,
        GRAPH_SCOPES.USER_READ,
        GRAPH_SCOPES.API_CALL
      ]
    }
  };

    export const msalApp = new UserAgentApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: "react_app_azure_client_id",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        validateAuthority: true,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE()
      }
    });
```

useAuthProvider hook:

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { msalApp, requiresInteraction, fetchMsGraph, isIE, GRAPH_ENDPOINTS, GRAPH_REQUESTS
           } from "./../utils/auth-util";

     // If you support IE, our recommendation is that you sign-in using Redirect APIs
    const useRedirectFlow = isIE();
    // const useRedirectFlow = true;

    export default function useAuthProvider() {
     const [account, setAccount] = useState(null);
     const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
     const [error, setError] = useState(null);
     const [graphProfile, setGraphProfile] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        async function doAuth() {
         msalApp.handleRedirectCallback(error => {
           if (error) {
      const errorMessage = error.errorMessage
        ? error.errorMessage
        : "Unable to acquire access token.";
      // setState works as long as navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
      setError(errorMessage);
    }
  });

  const account = msalApp.getAccount();

  setAccount(account);

  if (account) {
    const tokenResponse = await acquireToken(
      GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN,
      useRedirectFlow
    );

    if (tokenResponse) {
      setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken);
      const graphProfile = await fetchMsGraph(
        GRAPH_ENDPOINTS.ME,
        tokenResponse.accessToken
      ).catch(() => {
        setError("Unable to fetch Graph profile.");
      });

      if (graphProfile) {
        setGraphProfile(graphProfile);
      }
    }
  }
}

   doAuth();
   }, []);

     async function acquireToken(request, redirect) {
       return msalApp.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(error => {
         // Call acquireTokenPopup (popup window) in case of acquireTokenSilent failure
         // due to consent or interaction required ONLY
         if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
         return redirect ? msalApp.acquireTokenRedirect(request) : 
                msalApp.acquireTokenPopup(request);
         } else {
          console.error("Non-interactive error:", error.errorCode);
        }
      });
    }

      async function onSignIn(redirect) {
       if (redirect) {
         return msalApp.loginRedirect(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN);
       }

const loginResponse = await msalApp
  .loginPopup(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN)
  .catch(error => {
    setError(error.message);
  });

if (loginResponse) {
  setAccount(loginResponse.account);
  setError(null);

  const tokenResponse = await acquireToken(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN).catch(
    error => {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  );

  if (tokenResponse) {
    setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken);
    const graphProfile = await fetchMsGraph(
      GRAPH_ENDPOINTS.ME,
      tokenResponse.accessToken
    ).catch(() => {
      setError("Unable to fetch Graph profile.");
    });

        if (graphProfile) {
           setGraphProfile(graphProfile);
          }
        }
      }
    }

     function onSignOut() {
        return msalApp.logout();
     }

     return {
       account,
       accessToken,
       error,
       graphProfile,
       onSignIn: () => onSignIn(useRedirectFlow),
       onSignOut: () => onSignOut()
     };
    }
```

I created an httpService which is just a wrapper for axios. I am using this service to call the api and the configuration of the httpService is as follows and is where I need the access token. I tried below but I am getting hooks can only be called inside a function body.

```
import axios from "axios";
import useAuthProvider from "./useAuthProvider";

   axios.interceptors.request.use(
     config => {
     const { accessToken } = useAuthProvider();

   if (accessToken) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
   }        
      return config;
 },
   error => {
     Promise.reject(error);
   }
  );

   export default {
      get: axios.get,
      post: axios.post,
      put: axios.put,
      delete: axios.delete
   };
```

If user is not logged in I want to display a component with a Sign-In button which the prompts a user for credentials. I am doing this in the App component and its working perfectly.

App.js

```
   import React from "react";
   import useAuthProvider from "./services/useAuthProvider";
   import NavBar from "./components/navigation/navBar";
   import "./App.css";
   import Welcome from "./components/welcome";

   function App() {
    const { account, accessToken, onSignIn } = useAuthProvider();

    if (account === null)
      return <Welcome authButtonMethod={onSignIn.bind(this)} />;
    return <NavBar />;
  }

    export default App;
```

I can work with having the token in local storage then get it from there in the httpService. Based on my code above where can I access the token and save it in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

> I can successfully sign but I don't know how to acquire the
>   access_token to call the API.

As you can successfully sign, you already have a cached token in local storage(cacheLocation: "localStorage"). If the token hasn't expired, you can get it silently.

```
var accessToken = await this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: config.scopes
      });
```

If you want to access your own webapi, the scopes should be something like `api://{api_azure_client_id}/user_impersonation`.

Comment: I am seeing this in the console: **Token is not in cache for scope: api://{api_azure_client_id}/user_impersonation**. Then it seems to get stuck at **Renew token  for scope api://{api_azure_client_id}/user_impersonation is in progress. Registering call ball.**

Comment: @Munhu Didn't you configure the same scope for login usage?

Comment: Yes I did. My config is as above.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sign method, you can save the access token to local storage by adding window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken',tokenResponse.accessToken);

```
async function onSignIn(redirect) {
       if (redirect) {
         return msalApp.loginRedirect(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN);
       }

const loginResponse = await msalApp
  .loginPopup(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN)
  .catch(error => {
    setError(error.message);
  });

if (loginResponse) {
  setAccount(loginResponse.account);
  setError(null);

  const tokenResponse = await acquireToken(GRAPH_REQUESTS.LOGIN).catch(
    error => {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  );

  if (tokenResponse) {
    setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken);
    window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken',tokenResponse.accessToken);
    const graphProfile = await fetchMsGraph(
      GRAPH_ENDPOINTS.ME,
      tokenResponse.accessToken
    ).catch(() => {
      setError("Unable to fetch Graph profile.");
    });

        if (graphProfile) {
           setGraphProfile(graphProfile);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In the httpService to get the token from the local storage add window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken'); and then pass it to Axios header